# How to optimize bulk operation on PHP?

Tags: php, optimization, soap, sms, bulk

I wrote a function that send bulk SMS (via SOAP) in foreach cycle:

```
$sms = json_decode($response);
foreach($sms->data as $mydata)      
{
    $client->sendSmsOne($sessid, $mydata->phone, $mydata->from, $mydata->text);
}
```

**The question:** if there is a 100 items, how it will be proceed in foreach cycle? Can it brake my app? May be I need to use something like a counter in do while function with pause after each operation?

Comment: Purely depends on how many requests you can send the server a second. It'll likely be specified in the API.

Comment: If you have a lot of data entries your biggest issue will be timeouts and memory allocation while the loop finishes, your best bet would be to implement a queue, so your foreach would fire an event to queue the sending, and use something like beanstalkd to actually handle the sending of the requests.

Comment: Are you sure the service you're using does not provide methods for bulk operations? You're currently sending these messages one-by-one but there is probably a method you can call and pass data as array. Did you check this in the service documentation?

Comment: @Nima, nice idea. Not sure that this option exist, but I will ask my provider for this feature.